# contract vertices in igraph r preserving all nodes attributes?

Tags: r, igraph

I need to merge several vertices of a graph. I have used the igraph `contract` function, which works well but doesn't allow me to get the original type data. In addition, the function doesn't remove the collapsed vertices (in the example: 4 and 8).

```
G <- graph.ring(10)
V(G)$character <- rep(c("attr1","attr2"),5)
V(G)$numeric <- rep(1:5,2)
V(G)$newId <- c(1,2,3,3,5,6,7,7,9,10)

G1 <- contract(G, V(G)$newId, vertex.attr.comb = toString)

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(G)
plot(G1)
```

The result produces only character format values, in addition to grouping the values of the collapsed vertices. I tried different options of vertex.attr.comb. Because I have character and numeric data, the sum options do not work, and "first" or "last" don't retain all the data. Other options, like list all attributes didn't work.

Therefore, I don't know how to get a single value for each vertex instead of two or more, nor how to manipulate the obtained values.

Also, I have to remove the collapsed vertices. In my case I can do it with `delete.vertices (G,V(KeyW)[degree(G)==0)`, but it doesn't seem the ideal solution when they are intended to be kept isolated from the original network.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Update

If you want some additional manipulations for the attribute per node, you can use `lapply` like below

```
V(G1)$numeric <- unlist(lapply(V(G1)$numeric, sum))
```

and you will obtain

```
> V(G1)$numeric
 [1] 1 2 7 0 5 1 5 0 4 5
```

---

## `contract` graph and wrap attributes

I guess you can try concatenate the attributes, e.g., `vertex.attr.comb = c`

```
G1 <- contract(G, V(G)$newId, vertex.attr.comb = c)
```

and the attributes of the `G1` are saved in a list, e.g.,

```
> str(V(G1)$character)
List of 10
 $ : chr "attr1"
 $ : chr "attr2"
 $ : chr [1:2] "attr1" "attr2"
 $ : chr(0)
 $ : chr "attr1"
 $ : chr "attr2"
 $ : chr [1:2] "attr1" "attr2"
 $ : chr(0) 
 $ : chr "attr1"
 $ : chr "attr2"

> str(V(G1)$numeric)
List of 10
 $ : int 1
 $ : int 2
 $ : int [1:2] 3 4
 $ : int(0)
 $ : int 5
 $ : int 1
 $ : int [1:2] 2 3
 $ : int(0)
 $ : int 4
 $ : int 5

> str(V(G1)$newId)
List of 10
 $ : num 1
 $ : num 2
 $ : num [1:2] 3 3
 $ : num(0)
 $ : num 5
 $ : num 6
 $ : num [1:2] 7 7
 $ : num(0)
 $ : num 9
 $ : num 10
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas, but how do I get the sum or the first value in cases of collapsed vertices? I tried the following expression but it returns the previous data (assigns to collapsed vertices).

``` V(G1)$numeric2 <- as.numeric(unlist(V(G1)$numeric)) ```

Comment: @Sebastián See my update

Comment: Thank you @ThomasIsCoding. With this information you can also eliminate the vertices with value 0 (as long as the others sum different from 0, otherwise a simple way would be to add a constant before the contract function).