# Handling vertex attribute in an igraph shrinked network

Tags: r, igraph

This query follows another one ([contract vertices in igraph r preserving all nodes attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77413654/contract-vertices-in-igraph-r-preserving-all-nodes-attributes)) about collapsing a network preserving attribute information. I have been trying to extract text from igraph attribute objects. The attributes are not atomic vectors because they are results of igraph's contract function, as a way to get both character and numeric attribute data:

```
g <- graph_from_literal(1,2-3-4,5-6,7).
V(g)$label <- c("wood", "wood products", "work", "work environment",
                "work environments", "young", "young consumers")
V(g)$number <- c(1,2,1,2,1,2,2)
g <- contract(g, mapping=c(1,1,3,4,4,6,7), vertex.attr.comb=c)
g <- delete.vertices(g, which(V(g)$name=="character(0)"))
```

I need to get only one label, for example the first one, in cases where there are more than one. I tried with:

```
first <- stri_extract_first_regex(V(g)$label, "[a-z]+")
```

But the result yields "c" in cases of a single text, instead of the corresponding labels.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I get `Error in contract(g, mapping = c(1, 1, 3, 4, 4, 4, 6, 7), vertex.attr.comb = c) : 
  At core/operators/contract.c:78 : Invalid mapping vector length, Invalid value`

Comment: Are you just looking for something like `sapply(V(g)$label, \`[\`, 1)`?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I correct a mistake in the contract line. There was 8, instead of 7 labels.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to keep the first entry of all attributes, you should use `vertex.attr.comb = first`

```
g <- contract(g, mapping = c(1, 1, 3, 4, 4, 6, 7), vertex.attr.comb = first)
```

and you will see that

```
> V(g)$label
[[1]]
[1] "wood"

[[2]]
character(0)

[[3]]
[1] "work"

[[4]]
[1] "work environment"

[[5]]
character(0)

[[6]]
[1] "young"

[[7]]
[1] "young consumers"


> V(g)$name
[[1]]
[1] "1"

[[2]]
character(0)

[[3]]
[1] "3"

[[4]]
[1] "4"

[[5]]
character(0)

[[6]]
[1] "6"

[[7]]
[1] "7"
```

---

In addition, if you want to remove the vertices with "empty" attributes, you can try

```
g <- contract(g, mapping = c(1, 1, 3, 4, 4, 6, 7), vertex.attr.comb = first)
g <- delete.vertices(g, lengths(V(g)$name) == 0)
```

and then you will see

```
> V(g)$label
[[1]]
[1] "wood"

[[2]]
[1] "work"

[[3]]
[1] "work environment"

[[4]]
[1] "young"

[[5]]
[1] "young consumers"


> V(g)$name
[[1]]
[1] "1"

[[2]]
[1] "3"

[[3]]
[1] "4"

[[4]]
[1] "6"

[[5]]
[1] "7"
```

Comment: Thanks. But in that way I would lose information about other attribute (as I mentioned and now included in the example). For that attribute I must preserve all the information (as a sum of values). That's why I need the "c" option instead of "first", in vertex.attr.comb, otherwise I would lose information.

Comment: Based in @Axeman, I solved with: V(g)$label <- sapply(V(g)$label, `[`, 1)  ; and: 
V(g)$number <- unlist(lapply(V(g)$number, sum))

Comment: @Sebastián yes and of course you can use `sapply` to fetch the first instead of `vertex.attr.combo = first`, definitely depending on your needs